# What's the difference between "laser" and "scan" of tf

Tags: ros, laser, roslaunch, scan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 50">
 </node>
```

When I write the above. I'm not clear about the names of tf frames, especially for the "laser". Is this argument always like this even if my sensor topic is "/scan" ? Does it mean the frame name is given by a name space and it has no relation to topic names?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254906/what%27s-the-difference-between-%22laser%22-and-%22scan%22-of-tf/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short: Yes, there is no direct relation.

Long: There are two things to distinguish here:

1. The name of the laserscan topic, which e.g. for amcl and gmapping defaults to "scan".
2. The tf-frame in which your laser publishes. This is the value of the field "frame_id" in the header of your "scan"-topic. Usually this is what you named your sensor in your urdf-file and has to reflect the position of the laserscanner on your robot. E.g. your laserscanner can have an offset of 1m to your base_link. With a tf transform this offset is automatically added to all scan data.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1